# ForLoop is always returning not_prime Assemblyx86 32bit

Tags: c, assembly, x86, primes

I'm very new at assembly. We are working with a 32bit assemblyx86. I am trying to refactor this C-code into assembly.

```
//C code
    for (i=2; i*i<=n; i++){
      if ((n%i)==0){
        is_prime=false;
          break;
       }
}
//=================================================
;ASSEMBLY CODE
;eax will contain the read in integer
forLoop:
mov edx, eax ; copy eax into edx
imul eax, edx ; multiply eax by edx value stored in eax
mov edx, 0 ; set remainder to 0
cmp eax, ecx ; if eax * eax
jg skip ; if greater than jump to skip.
mov ebx, eax ;  move to divide
div ebx ; restore eax
mov edx, 0 ; set divisor to 0
mov ebx, eax ; copy iterator to divisor
push eax ; save iterator
mov eax, ecx ; copy n to numerator
div ebx ; divide EAX/EBX
pop eax ; restore iterator
add eax, 1 ; inc iterator
cmp edx, 0 ; compare divisor to 0
jne forLoop
mov dword [ebp-4], 0
jmp skip

Sample Output
1
not prime
2
prime
3
prime
4
not prime 
5
not prime
6
not prime
7
not prime
8
not prime
9
not prime
0
```

So the for_loop is the only thing that is setting my boolean to false essentially and having it print_not_prime.Therefore I think when I divide the remainder for edx isn't being set properly! I'm rather confused.

Comment: `div ebx ; restore eax` I don't understand that. Anyway, use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: gotcha, basically since I'm doing i*i that value is stored in eax and so I divide it by moving the original value i into ebx and then dividing it so I restore the iterator before the squaring it.

Comment: `mov ebx, eax; div ebx` will always give you `1` since you divide `eax` by itself. Anyway, `i` would still be in `edx` if you didn't zero it, you could just copy it back. Or even better, don't clobber it in `eax`, just do the `i*i` into `edx` or wherever (ie. `imul edx, eax`).

Comment: Does one know how to input a number in gdb so I can actually see what is going on within the forloop??

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `input`... you can set and print registers and if your program asks for input on stdin you can enter that. If it needs command line arguments you can use `set args` or add as parameter to `run` or even the `gdb --args` command.

Comment: Well that was the problem...thanks a lot! I knew I was overlooking something incredibly simple.

Answer (score 0):

mov ebx, eax; div ebx will always give you 1 since you divide eax by itself. Anyway, i would still be in edx if you didn't zero it, you could just copy it back. Or even better, don't clobber it in eax, just do the i*i into edx or wherever (ie. imul edx, eax). – Jester